# j2 template to variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a list of EC2 servers launched by the [EC2](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_module.html) module.

How can I create the following string for a future command, and dump it to the terminal?

```
-hosts=private_ip1:private_ip2:private_ipn
```

I have a `j2` template which creates this string, but I cannot find a way to register this output to a variable.

Comment: You mean you are looking for the `set_fact` module, just not know its name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm using localhost as the host group, I solved it using set_fact and a j2 loop directly in the value:

```
- name: Set some fact
  set_fact:
    render_host_command: "-myarg={% for item in aws_instances %}{{ item.private_ip }}{%- if not loop.last %}:{% endif -%}{% endfor %}"
```